# Adjoint Operator with Matrix

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \Bbb R^n$ and $L$ be a linear differential operator 1 $$L:V\to W, V:=\mathcal C^1_0(\Omega;\Bbb R), W:=\mathcal C^0_0(\Omega; \Bbb R^{n*n})$$
$$L(u):=(\partial_j u_j - \partial_i u_j)_{i,j=1,...n}$$ equipped with the following inner products $$\lt u,v\gt_V:=\int_\Omega\sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i , \qquad <u,v>_W:=\int_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n u_{i,k} v_{i,k} dx$$ show that the adjoint operator $L^*:W \to V$ is $L*(A)=-2div ($A$^a)$. $\\$
For a martix $A:=(a_{ik})_{i,k=1,...n}$, the anti-symmetric part $A^a$ of $A$ defined as $A^a:=\frac{1}{2}(A-A^T),$ and the divergence of $A$ is defined by $$div A :=(\sum _{k=1}^{n} \frac{\partial a_{i,k}}{\partial x_k})_{i=1,..n}$$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

$\Omega$ is an open set.

I think $C_0^n$ means $n$ times differentiable with compact support? Compact support is essential to be able to do partial integration and throw away the boundary terms. (So $\int_\Omega g(\partial_i f) = - \int_\Omega (\partial_i g)f$)

With the form of $L^*$ given it is clear that we will have some trouble, $L^*$ is not defined on the entire vector space since not every element of $C_0^0(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^{n*n})$ is differentiable.

So lets look at some dense subset $D$ of $W$, can we find an $L^* : D \to V$ so that $<A,L u>_W = <L^* A, u>_V$ for all $A \in D$ and all $u\in V$?

Doing the calculation and assuming $A \in C^1_0(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^{n*n})$, we get:

$$<A,Lu>_W=\int A_{i,j} (\partial_j u_i - \partial_i u_j)=-\int (\partial_j A_{i,j})u_i + \int (\partial_i A_{i,j})u_j =-\int (\partial_j (A_{i,j}-A_{j,i}))u_i\\= -\int\text{div}(A-A^T)_i u_i \overset{!}{=}<L^*A,u>_V$$

Where the sum is taken over any indices appearing twice.

Comment: Would you please explain the lines 9 and 10 more?

Comment: I think the problem you have is with how the derivatives move over from $u$ terms to $A$ terms? This is partial integration. I will fill out more details when I have more time tomorrow.

Comment: Okay, I got it, but I think there is not first part of integration. is it 0? because $\partial A_{i,j}$ is equal 0?

Comment: Partial integration in 1 dimension is this: $\int_0^1 \partial_x f(x) g(x) dx = f(x)g(x) \vert_0^1 - \int_0^1 f(x)\partial_x g(x)$. If either $f$ or $g$ vanish on  $[0,1]$, then the boundary term drops out. Here we have a higher dimensional case and we are integrating over an open set $\Omega$. But the things we integrate have compact support, this makes the boundary terms zero and partial integration will work in the way that derivatives are moved to the function on the left with the effect of a minus sign.